# hiding listItem seperator for few items in Navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am working on an android application with Navigation drawer. In my nav drawer, I need to show two different lists one-after-another.
I browsed through google apps and observed that they have hiden the listSeperator for few of the list items, so it looks different than the other list.

I want to achieve the same effect for my navigation drawer. Please help me understanding the drawer implementation.
1. Are these two different lists stacked on one another
or
2. they have included list inside listItem.
3. is there any other method to achieve this

thanks,
Rajan

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a list inside listitem...They must be two different lists stacked one below the other..

and in your xml file add this Tag to ListView to remove line seperator..

```
<ListView
 ...
android:divider="@null"
 ...
</ListView>
```

Comment: I tried implementing that, but the two lists stacked on each other are not scrolling as a single list. They have their own scrollbars.